# Can't properly select a date in Google Calendar with iMac Magic Mouse

Tags: google-calendar

The task is straightforward enough. I wish to click on a specific date from the calendar that appears on the left side of Google Calendar. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Let's say I want to select the 24th. In any sane world I'd simply click on the "24". But in my case, clicking on "24" causes the calendar to do some kind of hyper-scroll back to November 28, 2014 as shown here:

[image]

I can actually see it scrolling as I make the click. Recall that the face of the iMac's mouse is sensitive to movement and is used for scrolling. I believe that the Google calendar is somehow interpreting my click as a massive scroll.

This happens on every (iMac) computer that uses the standard mouse -- and I don't have a shaky hand either. The only way I can actually click a day in this calendar is to use the site on my laptop and click the day using the trackpad instead of a mouse.

There are some workarounds I can use to select the proper date but they're somewhat tedious. Any ideas on how to rectify?

Comment: My name is Festus.

Comment: This is Festus again. Just checking in.

Comment: Hi everyone, it's Festus. Just seeing what's up.